# Cannot read property 'cum' of undefined -- when creating a stacked area chart with xAxis.type=datetime

Tags: highcharts

When a create a stacked area chart with datetime x-axis, I see an error in console, and the series are not drawn.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: { type: 'area' },
  plotOptions: { series: { stacking: true } },
  xAxis: [ { type: 'datetime' } ],
  series: [
    {name:'foo', data:[1,2,3,4,5].map(function(d,i) { return {x:new Date(2013,i,1),y:d*d  }; })},
    {name:'bar', data:[1,2,3,4,5].map(function(d,i) { return {x:new Date(2013,i,1),y:d*d*d}; })} ]
});
```

Here is an example of the error: http://jsfiddle.net/bU2Ej/

Has anyone encountered similar problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify x coordinate for every point, use the following format of "data" :

An array of arrays with two values
Example ... data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]

In your case, instead of doing

```
data:[1,2,3,4,5].map(function(d,i) { return {x:new Date(2013,i,1),y:d*d  })
```

do this

```
data:[1,2,3,4,5].map(function(d,i) { return [new Date(2013,i,1),d*d  ]; })
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bU2Ej/1/

Comment: Thank you.  You're right, passing arrays-of-arrays works.  My concern is that the array-of-objects data format works just fine for other chart types/x-axis type combinations.  I'll use the workaround you suggested for now, but hope that it gets fixed in the library.

Comment: It seems that array-of-arrays solution screws up the x-axis.  What I found to work is using int representation of the date:  

    {name:'foo', data:[1,2,3,4,5].map(function(d,i) { return {x:new Date(2013,i,1).getTime(),y:d*d  }; })},

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ac8U5/1/